# Tooltip for comment timestamp — Why does it contain "License: cc by-sa 4.0"

Tags: discussion, tooltips

When I mouseover “yesterday”, why am I getting the tooltip below?

[image: 2020-11-10 21:20:36Z License: cc by-sa 4.0]

Is your timestamp mechanism licensed?

Seems such an odd place to put license information. I started wondering why this might be the case?

This isn't the case for all timestamps, only noticed it just now for timestamps on comments.

Comment: Your comment is licensed with that not that feature. Why do you think they mean the feature?

Comment: As I said, I really struggled to understand what is licensed in that case. Is my comment any thing special comared to the question/answer, which doesn't have the license information?

Comment: The comments are licensed at the time they are posted, [just like the posts themselves](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/402835/timeline). Further reading on Meta Stack Exchange: [Creative Commons Licensing UI and Data Updates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347758/241919)

Comment: The licence that [se] and [so] used changed last year, however, rather than apply the new licence to all existing material (which they initially appeared to want to do and suffered a huge backlash from the community) it only applied to new material. Thus material needs to demonstrate what licence it is under. [An Update On Creative Commons Licensing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344491/an-update-on-creative-commons-licensing.)

Comment: Question/answers have that info too. Check the [timeline](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/402835/timeline).

Comment: Didn't know about the timeline feature, thanks for that. Tough it kinda raises the question, why didn't the timeline get updated with a column license and each row could have a different license. But maybe this question was raised and answered in the shared URLs, will have to read. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Update: just noticed that the timeline actually has a license column, which makes the tooltip useless or?

Comment: The timeline contains info about the post's (question or answer) license and changes due to edits, not the comment's license. Using that column for the comment license info would probably be too confusing, it's kind of reserved for the post itself. E. g. imagine an old post with license 3.0 receiving a new comment with license 4.0. The impression could be created that the post's license changed although it didn't.

Comment: Worth adding, you can also see the license by clicking the "share" button under a post.

Comment: It would make more sense to put this information in the License column in the timeline.

Comment: @DonaldDuck It's typically put in places where the license itself *requires* it to be put.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

That’s the license for the comment.  [Stack Overflow changed licenses in 2018](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344491/323179), so content posted since then is CC BY SA 4, and anything older is 3 (except the really old content that’s 2.5).

You can also see what license posts are under by using the [timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/344491/timeline), found by clicking on the icon underneath the vote and save icons on the left of each post.

Comment: Why not mentioning it in the TOS instead?

Comment: @JuanC.Roldán Because exactly what is licensed under which license is non-trivial, and there was more than a little sentimement against the TOS after a version which stated all content was CC BY SA 4.0, even stuff that had only ever been licensed under version 3 or 2.5.

Comment: Why did they put the license in the tooltip on timestamps for **comments**, but not in the tooltip on timestamps for **question/answers**?

Comment: @GregSchmit because it already exists for Q/A in the timeline as described above. For comments, there is really nowhere else to put it...